# Help using av jack on pi 2

Tags: pi-2, composite-video

Help please
I have a portable DVD player with an audio/video input and it works with all devices except my raspberry pi 2. I also need it to fit in the DVD player case so I soldered the video cable to pp24 video and pp6 ground on the pi but I get no signal.
All help is appreciated

From
Krutav Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out you need to hold shift 4 depending on PAL or NTSC and it will boot in composite mode. Then you go in config.txt and uncomment hdmi hotplug